# Stop multiple upgrades

Tags: upgrade

out in the boonies on slow DSL. Often **sudo apt upgrade** will show two programs being upgraded simultaneously as in

[firefox 37%] [freecad 28%] 15m 45s

I'd like to make that only one at a time so I can Ctrl-C and stop the process if I need to, as in, like right now. It is going to take another 15-minutes at the current speed. I hate having to lose what is already started, but I have to stop it.

Is there an option for one-at-a-time for future use?

Thanks

Comment: Try CTRL+C to stop downloading, then try upgrading again. The download should resume from where you stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress meter indicates that the installation is still in the downloading stage.

There is no harm cancelling downloads even if there are multiple downloads happening at once, and APT will try to resume, rather than start from the beginning, if you try to download again later.  If this is not working for you, try changing your mirror in your APT sources.  In fact, this may also fix the slow download speed as well.

Once the updates are downloaded, they are installed one at a time.  Cancelling during this installation is not recommended, though it is still possible to repair a partially installed package.

Comment: OK, thanks to you both, but the resume after Ctrl-C did not take place. It started back at the beginning of both Firefox and Freecad. But it just finished upgrading so all good for a few more weeks/months. :)